# Firebase redirects the user to localhos instead of the app deep link after signInWithRedirect

Tags: cordova, firebase

I'm trying to implement [firebase social login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova) in my cordova app. When i run the app in the browser, everything works fine, but when i run the app in a real device, firebase redirects the user to localhost:8080 instead of the app deep link!